# EGitでjarや画像ファイルをプッシュについて教えてください

Tags: git, eclipse

eclipseでjarや画像ファイル(バイナリファイル)をGitへプッシュしようとすると
エラーになってしまいますが、SourceTreeで同様の処理を実施すると問題なくプッシュできました。

> Failed pushing to pub - origin
>   http://■■■■/pub.git: Error writing request body to server

[image: プッシュした後でてくる結果]

eclipseでのGitへのjarや画像のプッシュは出来ないものなのでしょうか？

ツールバージョン
eclipse：MARS
[チーム-Git-ウィンドウ・キャッシュ設定]
　ウィンドウ・キャッシュ：700m　　← 追記
　ストリーム・ファイル閾値：350m　← 追記
(ウィンドウ・キャッシュ設定を実施することでどうなるのか理解できてません・・・。)
egit　　：4.1.1
gitlab(オンプレ)：10.8.4　← 追記

コミットファイルのサイズ：１M以上　← 追記

※ちなみに、jarに関してはGitではなくMavenリポジトリなどで管理するのが好ましいでしょうか？
(現在はCVSでリソース管理を実施しており、jarなど一括で管理しています。)

↓追記：eclipseのログ↓

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.core 4 0 2018-12-12 16：18：26.984
>   !MESSAGE An exception occurred during push on URI http：//ＸＸＸ/pub.git： http：//ＸＸＸ/pub.git： Error writing request body to server
>   !STACK 0
>   org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException： http：//ＸＸＸ/pub.git： Error writing request body to server
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java：164)
>       at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.PushOperation.run(PushOperation.java：228)
>       at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.push.PushOperationUI.execute(PushOperationUI.java：167)
>       at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.push.PushOperationUI$1.run(PushOperationUI.java：229)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java：55)
>   Caused by： org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException： http：//ＸＸＸ/pub.git： Error writing request body to server
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackPushConnection.doPush(BasePackPushConnection.java：218)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$SmartHttpPushConnection.doPush(TransportHttp.java：807)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackPushConnection.push(BasePackPushConnection.java：153)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushProcess.execute(PushProcess.java：166)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.push(Transport.java：1200)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand.call(PushCommand.java：157)
>       ... 4 more
>   Caused by： java.io.IOException： Error writing request body to server
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.checkError(HttpURLConnection.java：3479)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$StreamingOutputStream.write(HttpURLConnection.java：3462)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.util.TemporaryBuffer.switchToOverflow(TemporaryBuffer.java：329)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.util.TemporaryBuffer.reachedInCoreLimit(TemporaryBuffer.java：320)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.util.TemporaryBuffer.write(TemporaryBuffer.java：144)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.util.io.TimeoutOutputStream.write(TimeoutOutputStream.java：113)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.PackOutputStream.write(PackOutputStream.java：126)
>       at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java：253)
>       at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java：211)
>       at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java：97)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectLoader.copyTo(ObjectLoader.java：266)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.PackWriter.writeWholeObjectDeflate(PackWriter.java：1538)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.PackWriter.writeObjectImpl(PackWriter.java：1516)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.PackWriter.writeObject(PackWriter.java：1459)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.PackOutputStream.writeObject(PackOutputStream.java：164)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.writeObjects(WindowCursor.java：195)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.PackWriter.writeObjects(PackWriter.java：1447)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.PackWriter.writeObjects(PackWriter.java：1435)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.pack.PackWriter.writePack(PackWriter.java：998)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackPushConnection.writePack(BasePackPushConnection.java：306)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackPushConnection.doPush(BasePackPushConnection.java：198)
>       ... 9 more

↓追加：コマンド実行結果↓
[image: コマンド実行結果]

Comment: バイナリファイルだからエラーになるのではなく、ファイルサイズが大きくてタイムアウトになっているからエラーになっているのかもしれませんね。Eclipseのログには何か出力されていないでしょうか？

Comment: 参考: 英語版SOでの類似質問 - [Error writing request body to server - eGit - Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37656031/2322778)

Comment: かなり軽めの画像ファイルでも同様のエラーが出たのでタイムアウトは考えていませんでした。ログ確認したいと思います！※申し訳ありません…どこのログを見ればよいでしょうか？？

Comment: 類似質問見ましたが、SSHで解決ってことでしょうか？現在SSHはしない方向で話進んでいる感じです…。ただ、どうしてもSSHでなければ解決しそうにないのなら、考えないといけないかもしれないですかね…

Comment: コマンドラインからgitコマンドを試すことはできませんか？`git push -v`や`git push -vv`などで詳しい情報が得られるかもしれません。

Comment: @nyako eclipseのログはworkspaceの下の`.metadata/.log`です。

Comment: @ cubick♦ さん　@ Kohei TAMURA さんありがとうございます。お二人の助言参考させてもらい、ログとってみました。見る限りJavaのHTTPプロトコル関連が原因のようですね・・・。全く解決策思いつきません・・・

Comment: すみません・・・。もしやEGitのバグな気がしてきましたが、かなり過去のバグで関連があるのか怪しいです・・・ 　[Eclipseバグノート](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402442)

Comment: もしその問題と同等であれば、[Window Cacheの設定で回避可能](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402131#c11)かもですね。巨大なファイルがコミットされているようなリポジトリに対する操作で発生する、ように読めます。

Comment: ちなみにEclipse Mars.2, GitLab11.5.3 でjarファイルとpng画像ファイルをpush(over http)してみましたが正常に行えましたので、"eclipseでのGitへのjarや画像のプッシュは出来ない"ということはないと思います。

Comment: @yukihaneさん Window Casheの設定を実施しましたが、だめでした・・・。ちなみにEgitのバージョンって同じでしょうか？？

Comment: Mars.2にはじめから入っているバージョン `4.1.1.201511131810-r` で試しました。

Comment: @yukihaneさん 返信ありがとうございます。同じバージョンぽいですね…。一度gitlab最新化して、試してみます！

Comment: すみません！検証不足でした。Windowキャッシュの設定を実施したところ、jarはUPできませんでしたが、比較的軽い画像ファイルはUPすることができました。jarは１Mくらいあるのですが、これはUPしちゃいけないものなんでしょうか。。。

Comment: 何度もすみません・・・。**１Mに満たないjar**はUPすることが出来ました。普通１Mを超えるデータをGitで管理しないほうがいいんでしょうか・・・

Comment: サイズの大きいファイルやバイナリファイルをGitで扱う場合は"Git LFS"という仕組みがあるので、こちらを参考にしてみて下さい。 - [Git LFS | GitLab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/lfs/manage_large_binaries_with_git_lfs.html)

Comment: [1]"コミットを実施しようとした際のウィンドウで通常はチェックが入るのにチェックが入らず表示されてしまいます"については、バージョン管理対象でない(まだ1度もコミットしていない、ハテナアイコンの)ファイルだからでしょう。今回の問題とは無関係かと考えます。[2]EGitで失敗するものと同じpushが、SourceTreeでは正常に完了する、というのは正しいでしょうか(別ファイルで試してうまくいった、とかではなく)。[3]EGitでローカルリポジトリにpushしてみるとどうなりますか。ローカルリポジトリに対するpushが正常に完了するのであれば、ネットワーク設定やGitLab側設定の制限である可能性もあるかと思います。GitLab側のログには何か出力されていないでしょうか。

Comment: @ cubick♦　さん　GitLFSも最初考えていましたが、1MでLFSを導入かぁと首をかしげている状態です・・・最悪の場合は導入を検討してみますー

Comment: @ yukihane　さん　[1]：無知ですみません・・・。恥ずかしい限りです・・・[2]：はい。同じ環境。同じファイルをEGitとSourceTreeでpushしましたが、SourceTreeは成功し、EGitは失敗しました。[3]GitLab側のログは何をみればよいでしょうか？？`gitlab-ctl tail`で出力されるログにはそれらしいものはありませんでした。（ちなみにGitLabの`Maximum attachment size `は１０Mでした。）また、ローカルpushってことはローカルの別リポジトリにpushってことで認識あってますか？

Comment: デフォルトは `/var/log/gitlab/[プロダクトごとディレクトリ]`だったと思いますが、インストール方法によって変わるかもしれません。管理者やマニュアルに当たってみてください。ちなみに`Maximum attachment size`はGitリポジトリサイズとは無関係(Issueへの添付ファイルサイズ制限？)だったような。記憶の限りでは、転送ファイルサイズ(httpサーバ、nginxのコンフィグ)が関係しています。(仮にサーバ設定の問題だった場合、)どのファイルを編集すべきかも、インストール方法によって違うと思うので管理者/マニュアルを当たってみてください。

Comment: @ yukihane　さん。本当に早速の返信ありがとうございます。色々なヒントとともにマニュアルを見てみます！`Maximum attachment size`は関係なかったのですね・・・。申し訳ないです(恥)

Comment: "ローカルpushってことはローカルの別リポジトリにpushってことで認識あってますか？"についてはそのとおりです。EGitの問題か、それ以外(ネットワーク、Gitサーバ)の問題かを切り分けられると思います。/一応、[前述の環境](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/51143/egit%e3%81%a7jar%e3%82%84%e7%94%bb%e5%83%8f%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%e3%82%92%e3%83%97%e3%83%83%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a5%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6%e6%95%99%e3%81%88%e3%81%a6%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84#comment53412_51143)において、Eclipse,GitLabともデフォルト設定で175MB程度のバイナリファイルをpushしてみましたが、正常に終了しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すいません、通知が来なかったので、この件すっかり忘れてましたが、

EGitのビューで Repository (右クリック) -> Properties-> Add Entry で以下を追加したら、うまくいきませんかね？

- key: `http.postBuffer`
- value: `500000000` （※適当なバイト数）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 出来ました！！！ありがとうございます。前回は@のすぐ後ろに「さん」をつけたせいですかね・・・。すみません